# How do you use a RestorableProperty as a ChangeNotifier within a Flutter test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a widget that requires access to a `RestorableBool` outside itself. In my app, I'm able to provide the widget access to the property using the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). This works because `RestorableBool` is a (indirect) subclass of `RestorableProperty` which is a `ChangeNotifier`.

Example:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with RestorationMixin {
  final RestorableBool _importantState = RestorableBool(false);

  @override
  String? get restorationId => 'my_widget_state';

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket? oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    registerForRestoration(_importantState, 'important_state');
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider<RestorableBool>.value(
        value: _importantState,
        child: MotherWidget(
          children: <Widget> [
            DaughterWidget(), // this widget needs access to the RestorableBool
            // other widgets and their dependents that also need access to the RestorableBool
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to write an automated test for the `DaughterWidget`, and in order to do so, I have to provide it with the RestorableBool. The Flutter team explains how to do this in their YouTube video [Pragmatic State Management in Flutter (Google I/O'19)](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I?t=1848).

Example:

```
RestorableBool value = RestorableBool(false);
await tester.pumpWidget(
  ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
    value: value,
    child: DaughterWidget(),
  ),
);
```

The problem comes after the `DaughterWidget` retrieves the `RestorableBool` and tries to access its value using `theRestorableBool.value`. `RestorableBool.value` asserts that the `RestorableBool` has been registered for restoration, and since the `RestorableBool` has not been registered using `registerForRestoration`, I get the following error:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/restoration_properties.dart': Failed assertion: line 80 pos 12:
'isRegistered': is not true.
```

I could avoid this error by just instantiating `MyWidget` instead, but I'd like to achieve a more isolated test on the `DaughterWidget`. Is there a way to manually register a `RestorableProperty` for testing purposes such as this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the best solution I could come up with is to call `registerForRestoration` directly using one of the Flutter widgets that implements `RestorationMixin`, such as `FormFieldState`.

Example:

```
RestorableBool value = RestorableBool(false);
FormFieldState().registerForRestoration(value, 'test_value');
```

This isn't an *elegant* solution because the `registerForRestoration` method is annotated with `@protected`—essentially meaning it's only intended to be accessed by subclasses of RestorationMixin.

**A Little Explanation About the Error**

The reason this error occurs is because `isRegistered` fails if the `restorationId` of a `RestorableProperty` is `null`. It seems that the only way to provide a `restorationId` is by calling:

```
registerForRestoration(restorableProperty, 'custom_id')
```

which can be called from a custom widget that includes the `RestorationMixin` like OP does with `MyWidget` or called from a Flutter widget such as in the example above with `FormFieldState`.